# Dual monitors and flash movie to stay maximized on one of them

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, flash-player, fullscreen

I have recently assembled a dual monitor setup.

I often watch live.twit.tv in my browser and I would like to run it maximized while I do other stuff on second screen, but when I click on a desktop the full screen mode rolls back to normal view. The same case is for different Flash players and I believe Silverlight players suffer from the same problem.

Is there any way to bypass this behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It actually is possible to do! You do have to either hex edit a flash binary or you can use the one he supplied if you trust it.

["Watch fullscreen flash while working on another screen"](http://my.opera.com/d.i.z./blog/2009/04/22/watch-fullscreen-flash-while-working-on-another-screen)

Comment: Great! I love it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in more recent versions of flash this is supported by default. If someone can verify this we should update the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

http://lifehacker.com/5419028/keep-flash-videos-in-full-screen-on-dual-monitors

Windows only though.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do that with flash, but for the TWiT Live stream, you can use VLC to play the following stream: `http://bglive-a.bitgravity.com/twit/live/high` and that will allow you to play it on a second monitor in full screen.

Comment: Nice workaround!

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible. According to a reply to a [bug report](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-436%3Bjsessionid=8F55035D498D30D3B118B41537C00587) on Adobe:

> We understand that many users would like fullscreen on one monitor and to be able to interact with your OS on another monitor. However, due to security requirements, we require that Flash and Browser must be the current focus of your OS. Apologies if this causes any workflow or usability issues. We will continue to review our security policy and consider changes in the future.

Comment: It would be great if it would be a option a user could change.

Answer (score 2):

Some sites let you watch "pop out" screens. They stay maximized so you can work on the second monitor. An example of this is www.hulu.com - on the right side bar of the screen there is a menu - choose "pop out and a new screen opens up. I suggest you check the FAQ or search the knowledge base of the video sharing site and find out if they offer "pop out" screens.

Answer (score 2):

> If you have two or more monitors, then
>   you have probably experienced this:
>   When watching a fullscreen flash video
>   on one screen you go to work on the
>   other screen and flash immediately
>   exits fullscreen mode.
>
> **[FlashHacker](http://jmaxxz.com/)** is a tool which makes
>   hacking and unhacking a flash install
>   incredibly easy.  It should work on
>   most versions of flash.

[image]

1. Close all browsers (enables flashhacker to edit flash)
2. Run FlashHacker
3. Click 'Hack My Flash!'
4. Go back to browsing

Answer (score 1):

There's an automated program. See the discussion here. Or you can "pop out" a window (like on Hulu)

http://www.gavinr.com/2009/04/18/dual-monitors-full-screen-flash/

Answer (score 1):

There's another way, if you use Google Chrome.

Type `about:plugins` in the URL bar, and expand the +Details link where it says Flash (3 Files).

Disable the one that says Pepperflash at location `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\21.0.1180.60\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll`

When you restart Chrome, you'll find that flash video works as expected, and it will stay in fullscreen mode even if you click on other windows on your other monitor. Works for me with Flash 11.3 r300.